# Access in PFUser data in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfuser

I am running cloud code `beforeSave` on a PFObject. I would like to access a variable saved under a `PFUser` called `Index` and increment it by 1. However, it appears that I am not able to access the `Index` variable.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("CDParseSyncOperation", function(request, response) {

    var currentUser = request.user;
    var index = currentUser.get("Index");
    index = index + 1;

    request.object.set("Index", index);

    currentUser.set("Index", index);

    response.success();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to save the currentUser after setting the Index.

```
currentUser.save();
```